# What is the "Online Certificate Status Protocol"?

Tags: linux, security, http

I use privoxy. In the user.action file i have a redirect rule and a few websites:

```
{ +redirect{s@http://@https://@} }
.twitter.com
.facebook.com
```

Ok! it's working great, e.g.: if i visit any "*twitter.com" URL it gets redirected to HTTPS!

But: with wireshark i can see some [OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) packets.

Question: What are these packets? Why aren't there in HTTPS?

Is my redirection method with privoxy is secure?

Thank you for any tips/opinions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCSP is a way for programs that use X.509 certificates (such as anything using SSL, like web browsers for `https:` URLs) to check whether a certificate has been revoked because it was compromised.

You're not seeing them when using `https:` directly because you would need a packet tracer that can decrypt SSL *and* the SSL certificate used for encryption — which in most cases you won't have.

Comment: thanks, i checked again with wireshark, and i didn't see OCSP over HTTP

Comment: You won't see them for http; they're only useful with https, because only https uses certificates.

Answer (score 2):

It is a replacement for Certificate Revocation Lists. Instead of having to download a (very huge) list of all revoked certificates for each root certificate, a remote server can be queried for just the status of a specific certificate.